# how to grab a web image which has a dynamic src ID in python

Tags: python

it is not a static url but a address like xxx.xxx.com/xxx/run

the image is dynamically built based on daily status, so I can't grab it using its URL

is it possible to stimulate a browser and get the whole page contains the image? if then how?

thanks~

Comment: Can you link us to the site/image? Or at least give more details on how it changes?

Comment: I'm very sry dude but I'm doing something for company, it is not quite convenient, plus its an internal addr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways of doing this.

1. Use something like [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to grab the HTML of the page that your image is on, and then use something like [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) to parse the HTML and find the URL of your image. This should work in most cases, except when the URL isn't actually in the page's HTML (i.e. because it's put there by Javascript).
2. Use something like [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/), which lets you programmatically control an actual browser, to grab the URL. This is a bit more of a heavyweight solution, but it runs javascript like a normal browser (because it is).

The first option might look like this:
    import requests
    from pyquery import PyQuery

```
html = requests.get('http://example.com/').text
html_q = PyQuery(html)
image_url = html_q('img.my_image_class').attr('src')
```

Whereas the second might look like this:

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as b:
    b.visit('http://example.com/')
    image_url = b.find_by_css('img.my_image_class')['src']
```

Then, just download that URL as you would normally.

---

Edit: Here's another example with Requests, this time using a session to store cookies set by a login form. You'll have to get the URL and the keys for the data dictionary from the `<form>` and `<input>` elements on the login form; they won't always be `username` and `password`.

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
s.post('https://example.com/dologin', data={'username': 'adam', 'password': 'hunter2'})
html = s.get('https://example.com/other_page').text
# and continue as in the first example
```

Comment: the https page i want is auth required,i have tried r=requests.get('https: //xxx.xxx.com/xxx/run',auth=('xxx','xxx')),but the html i get is still the login page :(;

Comment: If you get a login page, the website isn't using HTTP basic auth, which is what `auth=` is for; it's giving your browser a form asking you to send it your login details in a POST request, and then it's setting a cookie in the response to that request; any subsequent requests must contain that cookie. You have two choices: use a Requests session to keep the cookie (I've updated the answer to show this), or use Splinter to fill in and submit the form (which you'll have to do if there's JS involved, unless you can reverse engineer it).

Comment: Thanks for your patient answer :) I'm new to python, and I'll keep trying on this~thanks again